# JS Node send JSON on PATCH with XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript

I try to send a JSON on a request on POST but it's not working

The code:

```
        let req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        req.open("PATCH", "https://discord.com/api/v8/users/@me/settings", true);
        req.setRequestHeader("authorization", token);
        req.setRequestHeader("content-type", "application/json");

        req.send(JSON.stringify({custom_status: "hello"}));
```

it's need to send on JSON.stringify custom_status: with the text "hello"
When i try this, it's don't give me any error / logs it's show nothing but it's not working

if someone can help me, thanks in advance